# filter admin access by IP with httpd.conf

Tags: drupal, users, httpd.conf, configuration

I am trying to filter all backend url to one IP in the httpd.conf file using this code:

```
<Location /admin>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 100.x.xxx.xxx
</Location>
```

This one works fine. I can't find a way to do the same with /?q=admin.

```
<Location /?q=admin>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 100.x.xxx.xxx
</Location>
```

Do I need some regular expression with backslash to escape some of the characters?

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86159)

Comment: My other post has been put on hold and someone advised me to post on webmasters as it seems not to be related precisely to drupal.

Comment: Yeah, they asked us if we wanted it moved here (which is the normal procedure) but since you already posted it I declined it. So it would have ended up here way, there's just more cleanup to do by cross-posting. No worries, though.

Comment: Did it work for you now?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend for the second one that has special characters that you use the `<LocationMatch>` Directive.

> The `<LocationMatch>` directive limits the scope of the enclosed
>   directives by URL, in an identical manner to `<Location>`. However, it
>   takes a regular expression as an argument instead of a simple string.
>   (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch)

For your particular case, use:

```
<LocationMatch /\?q=admin>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 100.x.xxx.xxx
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: I didn't succeed with this method but there is an answer here :  http://serverfault.com/questions/540288/filter-admin-access-by-ip-with-httpd-conf (my question was moved from Drupal to there)

Comment: Actually the statement "_The problem you're having is that <Location> (and <LocationMatch>) directives don't operate on query strings (the thing that comes after the ?)_" is inaccurate as `<LocationMatch>` uses RegEx which means it can take just about anything, as shown clearly in the documentation I linked to. However, if the method provided (which is inelegant to say the least) works for you, then that's all we want, so good luck :)